# Spotify iPhone API search by BPM

Tags: iphone, spotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0

I am implementing Spotify in my iPhone app. I want to search tracks by BPM. In Spotify, is there any API to search by BPM. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I don't believe that Spotify's search interface supports searching by tempo directly. You can add a "kudos" on this community thread:

> http://community.spotify.com/t5/Spotify-Ideas/Search-by-BPM-beats-per-minute/idi-p/335

The easiest way to do what you want might to be to use another metadata service to search by BPM and then cross-match your results against Spotify.

Comment: Thanks for your response. As you said, I could see a service EchoNest. It can search by BPM. But, how do I know whether the song is available in Spotify. Also, how to get its Spotify url.